# What does formality of a chain complex mean topologically?

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

I've been told that every topological abelian group is a product of Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces, but I don't have a reference for this fact. This confuses me because via the Dold-Kan correspondence, this should mean that every (nonnegatively-graded) chain complex of abelian groups is quasi isomorphic to a complex with zero differentials, ie that every complex is formal. But this is not the case.

So what am I missing? Maybe the weak equivalence between a topological abelian group and a product of Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces need not commute with the abelian group structure? But then where did this map come from?

Comment: Yes, the equivalence is not guaranteed to be an equivalence of topological abelian groups, just of spaces.

Comment: Do you know a way to interpret this equivalence in terms of chain complexes?

Comment: The problem is that it's unclear what the "underlying space" of a chain complex is. If you like, you can instead think about simplicial abelian groups, which have an obvious "underlying space," namely the underlying simplicial set.

Comment: Right. I agree.

Comment: If you work over a field, then every chain complex is formal as a chain complex. If you take chains of a topological abelian group you get a commutative Hopf algebra, and there is no reason why this Hopf algebra should be formal as a Hopf algebra. Obstructions to formality include various operations on (co)homology.